# External pagination vuetify data-table

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

I have object returned from API in the following format:

```
{
 "count": 0,
 "result": [
    {
     "id": "5dfbb8d5b2f68faf05688997",
     "createdOn": "1577121878136",
     "hash": "d7a3a552a2c1a765b3bcd935980a1982",
     "modifiedOn": "1577121878136",
     "company": {},
     "home": {},
     "first_name": "string",
     "last_name": "string",
     "isActive": true,
     "funding": "string",
     "medication": "string",
     "startDate": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using `vuex` to store data. How do I use `vuetify's` `v-data-table` to make pagination. The backend is paginated. And my api is `axios.get(..../?page='+page + '&count='+count)'` I need to pass `page` and `count` as argument to get paginated data.

I would be grateful if you could link me some of the resources to do it. I tried but I was not able to achieve it and did not find any materials for it. I followed `vuetify's docs` for `external pagination` but there it assumes the data are only externally paginated, they donot link to `veux store`.

Comment: clear one thing, do your api get paginated data? if you pass page and count properly?

Comment: I mean what is your problem? your problem to get data from api? or to show paginated data on `v-data-table` ?

Comment: @hasan05 the data I get from server is paginated, I need to show paginated data on `v-data-table` but using vuex and yes i need to pass page and count on the url.

Answer (score 2):

call v-data-table with these parameters.

```
<v-data-table
        :headers="yourHeadersArrayOfObject"
        :items="yourItemsArrayOfObject"    
        :page="yourCurrentPageNumber"
        :items-per-page="yourItemsPerPage"
        @update:page="pageUpdateFunction"
      ></v-data-table>
```

on methods handle page update =>

```
pageUpdateFunction(newPageNumber) {
  console.log(newPageNumber);
  // handle other axios request here and update varibles
},
```

Comment: Can I handle vuex state in the method ? I mean I wanted to store my object in the vuex store every time a new paginated request is made, and render that stored object.

Comment: nope. (Or may be, I don't know.).
what you can do is, you have to do this by computed property.